# React Native Login Button for iOS fbsdk

Tags: react-native-ios, react-native-fbsdk

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx1Ny.png)

I have followed every steps from [Facebook Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) until the ViewController step. I have struggled for two days on this problem. I even tried to use cocoapod for library tracing but it is not working. I ended up in the error picture shown above. Does anyone care to help please?
Thank you

Comment: let me know which file are you open .xcworkspace file or .xcodeproj ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to do react-native link react-native-fbsdk 
However, if you ever run into this error, you have to link react-native-fbsdk -> clean build on Xcode -> close Xcode -> run rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData on your terminal before you rebuild the project.